# How to return passed arguments in function in shell script?

Tags: shell

Below is code which I developed. I am passing four arguments in function and **want to return variable output which I am passing to that function as a argument number four**. I am getting below mentioned error.

test.sh

```
output='PASS'
A=(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0)
T=(1,2,3,4,5,6)
function compare(){
    j=0
    for i in "$2"
    do
            if [[ "$3" = '1.0' ]]
            then
                    "$4"="PASS" 
                    echo -e "\nA:$3 and T:$i sec" >> "$1"
            else
                    "$4"="FAIL"
                    echo -e "\nA:$3 and T:$i sec" >> "$1"
            fi
            j=$(( $j + 1 ))
    done
    return "$4"
}
result=compare $1 ${A[@]} ${T[@]} output
echo "result:$result"
```

When I call `./test.sh file.txt`, I get the following error:

> ./test.sh: line 13: output=FAILED: command not found
>
> ./test.sh: line 18: return: output: numeric argument required
>
> result=

Comment: You can't return "variable". Return is just the "return status" and can be a number from 0 to 255. No more, no less. You can, however, print the value in output to standard output `echo "$4"` and then grab the standard output of a command into a variable `result=$(compare ... )`. Return is used by `if`, as in `if compare ...`

Comment: You can't do `"$4"="smth"`, this will tr to run a comand named `$4=smth`. It needs to be a name `output="smth"`, you can't use `$` on the left side of the `=`. You can use eval `eval "$4=\"FAIL\""` which will re-evaluate/re-run the expression. Or you can use bash name reference / namerefs: `declare -n output_var=$4; output_var="smth"`

Comment: Also `A=(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0)` this is an array with _one_ element equal to `"1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0"`. If you want to use arrays, you need to expand the assignment on spaces or newlines as in `A=(1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 1.0)`. What is this code supposed to do? If we know, maybe we can help you.

Comment: I am comparing value in A(Digital o/p) with coresponding value in T(Time) and if all o/p is equal to 1.0 with respect to time then I am storing overall result ='PASS' and if one of the o/p is equal to 0.0 then overall result='FAIL' .@KamilCuk

Answer (score 0):

Lots of problems here:

- trying to assign a value to a variable *value* (this is the cause of the "output=FAIL" error you see)
- passing arrays as first-class values
- collecting output of the function

It's still not clear how A and T are related (settle down, techbros), but it looks like T contains the **index** you want to look up in A.

```
#!/bin/bash
# validate the bash version at least 4.4 here.

function compare(){
    local file=$1
    local -n arrayA=$2
    local -n arrayT=$3
    local -n resultVar=$4
    resultVar=PASS
    for i in "${arrayT[@]}"; do
        if [[ "${arrayA[i]}" != '1.0' ]]; then
            resultVar=FAIL
            # normally I would return here, but you want to log the whole array
        fi
        printf "A:%f and T:%d sec\n" "${arrayA[i]}" "$i" >> "$file"
    done
}

output='PASS'
T=(1 2 3 4 5 6)
A=([1]=1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 1.0)   # force A to start with index 1, corresponding to the first element of T

compare "$1" A T output
echo "result:$output"
```